# Historic Thompson-Reuters CRB Data?

Tags: data-request, finance, economics

Anyone know of a 20-30 year history of the Thompson-Reuters commodity index ([example](http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/CRY:IND))?

I looked through Quandl, but I didn't find the commodity index that is tied to this one - I found quite a few others.

Comment: Are you sure there is data before 2009? [view](http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/advchart/frames/frames.asp?show=&insttype=Index&symb=XX%3ACRB&time=20&startdate=1%2F4%2F1999&enddate=7%2F3%2F2016&freq=1&compidx=aaaaa%3A0&comptemptext=&comp=&ma=0&maval=9&uf=0&lf=1&lf2=0&lf3=0&type=2&style=320&size=2&x=60&y=3&timeFrameToggle=false&compareToToggle=false&indicatorsToggle=false&chartStyleToggle=false&state=8)

Comment: @philshem Yes sir/ma'am.

Comment: probably the best bet is to contact TR and ask for the history, or at least that index components, so you can recreate the price yourself.  I think that has to be somehow publicly available, although probably not machine readable.